# Accessing rowObejct inside custom formatter

Tags: jqgrid

In jqgrid wikki I have read that while using xml datatype rowobject will not be an array.
In json I got the column value using rowobject[1],[2],... and so on , but how can I achieve this with xml datatype.
Please provide solution to access rowobject inside custom formatter while using xml datatype.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use custom formatter together with xml datatype the `rowObject` parameter will be object represented the DOM element of the corresponding row of the XML input. The type of `rowObject` is `IXMLDOMElement`. To find the contain of the corresponding child element which correspond of the column 'myColumn' you can use for example

```
$(rowObject).find('myColumn').text()
```

If you use `loadonce:true` jqGrid parameter, then at the first load the `rowObject` parameter will be DOM element and at later as the named JavaScript object and the data which you need will be accessed as `rowObject.myColumn`.